# Erro ao tentar gravar o resultado no banco de dados

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

Gostaria de gravar o Nome do contato e o número do contato no banco. Assim posso utilizá-lo em outras activities.

Mas, ao retornar, da tela de contato para a Activity em questão, acontece um erro, me parece que não acha a Intent, a Activity, voltando então à Activity que estava na pilha, antes dela. Então, se puderem me ajudar a verificar onde está o erro. Muito Obrigado, segue abaixo os códigos e o erro (Há somente 1 dado na tabela):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r1-4F314D4F31/1
>   flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {projeto1.projeto_app/projeto1.projeto1_app.activity.ContatoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

```
   Button botaoBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscaContato1);
    botaoBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //buscar o Contato
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, NUMERO_BUSCA_CONTATO);
        }
    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String name;
        String num_tel;

        if(requestCode == NUMERO_BUSCA_CONTATO){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                                null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        int cNumber = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                        int cName = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

                        name = phones.getString(cName);
                        num_tel = phones.getString(cNumber);

                        //System.out.println("number is:" + cNumber);
                        //TextView editTelefone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContato1);
                       // editTelefone.setText(cName);

                        if (CriaBanco.NOME_CONTATO.isEmpty() &&
                                CriaBanco.NUM_TEL_CONTATO.isEmpty()) {
                            insereRegistro(name,num_tel);
                        }
                        else {
                            alteraRegistro(name,num_tel);
                        }

            //textContato();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
private void textContato() {

    criaBanco = new CriaBanco(getBaseContext());
    sqlNomeContato = "select nome_contato from tabela_contato";
    Cursor cursor = criaBanco.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlNomeContato, null);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContato1);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome_contato")));

    }
    else {
        textView.setText("Contato 1");
    }

    cursor.close();
}

private void insereRegistro(String nome, String num_tel) {

    bancoController = new BancoController(ContatoActivity.this);
    bancoController.insereDadoContato(nome, num_tel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava dentro de outro método, o que alteraria o registro. Estava com uma lógica errada então sempre cairia neste método, que estava em branco, o código (ID).